# Calculate the r.m.s value of $i = 20 + 100 \sin 100\pi t$ between $t = 0$ and $t = 1/50$.

Tags: integration

I am following a text book and there a a problem set.  It's a parametric equation. I need to take it's Integral, divide by the difference in t, and take the square root but I evaluate the integral to be nil.  However the result in the back of the book is rms = 73.485.

$i = 20 + 100 sin(100$ $\pi$t), and I get $\frac{di}{dt} = 10000 \pi cos (100$ $\pi t)$

The Integral is  $$\int_{0}^{1/50} 20 + 100 sin (100 \pi t)\frac{di}{dt}dt$$

On multiplying this out I get:

$$\int_{0}^{1/50} 200000  \pi cos (100 \pi t) + 1000000 \pi sin (100 \pi t) cos (100 \pi t) dt$$

On integrating (using the sine double angle theorem for the 2nd element) I get:

$2000 sin (100 \pi t)$  $ + 2500 (-cos(200 \pi t)$. Evaluated between t = 1/50 and t = 0, I think is 0.

Sorry if the formatting isn't great.

Could someone explain what I have done wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RMS value of current is given by 
$$I_{RMS} = \sqrt\frac{\int_0^t [I(t)]^2 dt}{t}$$
The formula you are using to calculate this value doesn't seem to be the same. You might want to double check with the textbook you are using.

Comment: I think that's probably going to be the answer.  The text book was correct, but I forgot what RMS was i.e. I forgot to square the original function.  

Thanks.  I knew there'd be an obvious error!

Comment: Thanks Aniruddha!  I re-did following your advice and get the answer I needed.  The previous questions were all about parametric equations and so I assumed this was a parametric equation, and I also forgot to square the function too.  I thought I had understood the material but this shows the example of doing a question. I was just following routines rather than thinking.